# Difference between two Times in MySQL by PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, difference

I have a database table build in this structure.

```
ID      - INT
addDate - DateTime
sunrise - Time
sunset  - Time
```

The Datasets look like
[image]

Now I'm trying to retrieve the difference in minutes between

```
SELECT addDate, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, sunrise, sunset) AS duration FROM SunData WHERE date(addDate) BETWEEN curdate() - interval 7 day and curdate() ORDER BY addDate ASC
```

The results I'm getting NULL in every row for duration.

Code to display these values

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('-','/',$row->addDate)));
$duration = $row->duration / 60;

echo "Dauer: " . $duration . "Stunden\n";
```

Why are the values getting less and less? Is my query correct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your query is getting the difference between the stored time and `NOW()`, ordered by the stored time, and all of those times are in the past. So, yes, those values would be decreasing.

Comment: Do you mean to find the difference between sunrise and sunset? I.E. The amount of daylight per day?

Comment: Changed it a bit... see edit...

Comment: if the above comment holds good.. then ur query should be select date(date) , time, time2,  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time, time2)/60 from test ; This will give you time in hours

Comment: `TIMEDIFF(sunset, sunrise)` gives you a nicely formatted interval (hh:mi:ss), `TIMEDIFF('16:11:50','06:26:13')` = `09:45:37`. If you prefer seconds, just wrap in `TIME_TO_SEC(...)` = `35137`

Comment: @JRD this solved it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are ordering by `addDate` in the ascending order. You are taking the difference between `now()` and `addDate`. Ascending order means `addDate` keeps getting bigger, so the difference between `addDate` and `now()` keeps getting smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your goal is- but with each record you getting closer to now()- that's why the values are getting less and less.

Your query don't use the sunrise and sunset fields:

```
SELECT addDate, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_ADD(addDate,sunset), DATE_ADD(addDate, sunrise))
```

Comment: This is not working. getting syntax error near at sunset)

Comment: as i read in mysql the function order is lower timestamp first - so the order is sunrise and then sunset

Comment: SELECT addDate,  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, DATE_ADD(addDate, sunrise), DATE_ADD(addDate, sunset)) AS duration FROM SunData WHERE date(addDate) BETWEEN curdate() - interval 7 day and curdate() ORDER BY addDate ASC => turns out syntax error

Comment: OK, checked and testet it now
since addData has a Time-portion i came to a complex one:
SELECT addDate, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                              ADDTIME(TIMESTAMP(DATE(addDate)), sunrise), 
                              ADDTIME(TIMESTAMP(DATE(addDate)), sunset)
                             ) / 60 As duration
                              from SunData

Comment: create table for testing: 
CREATE TABLE `SunData` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `addDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `sunrise` time NOT NULL,
 `sunset` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

and data

INSERT INTO `SunData` (`ID`, `addDate`, `sunrise`, `sunset`) VALUES
(5, '2015-10-30 19:58:42', '06:26:13', '16:11:50');